# What's the extent of the damage that lm_sensors can do?

Tags: hardware, sensors, lm-sensors

I started using lm_sensors in Ubuntu 22.04 (on a desktop PC) for the purpose of checking my CPU temperature and have a look at what other sensors there might be. I don't have much knowledge in the kernel and terminology used so I need some help. I have only went with the default yes/no to the questions it asks when running `sensors-detect`. However, some questions have warnings like these:

> Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to standard I/O ports to probe them. This is **usually safe**

> ... I2C/SMBus adapters ... This is the most risky part, and while it works reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to **cause trouble** on some systems.

For me, I don't get what does it refer to if something goes wrong to the "usually/normally safe" tests and what does it mean by "trouble".

What extent can the "trouble" caused by `lm_sensors` and `sensors-detect` be? Is it something that causes irreversible damage to the hardware that won't be back to normal and require PC parts replacement? or is the trouble something that a clean install of the OS or restoring a previous backup can get it back to normal?

Thank you

Comment: You never know. When you write to a bus not knowing what is at the other end, you don't know what can happen. But reboot most likely will restore the system.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 , from my search, the biggest trouble I saw someone mentioning was a display issue on a laptop. Are there incidents where damage was done?